# Java connecting to SQL Server Database - Login failed for user error message

Tags: java, sql-server, authentication

I have a Java program that is connecting to SQL Server database. When I try the connection using `integratedsecurity=true` it works and no issues. But when I try with hardcoding my windows username and password, I am getting a Login failed error. (I need to eventually use a service account, therefore I cannot use `integratedsecurity=true` and will need to pass a username and password which is different from my own).

This works:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://PRD:1435;databasename=PRD; multiSubnetFailover=true;integratedSecurity=true;");
```

This does not work:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://PRD:1435;databasename=PRD; multiSubnetFailover=true;User=domain\\username;password=pass");  (double slash for java.)
```

I tried different formats (with and without domain name etc)

Here is how I verified my username/password are correct:

1. I verify using SQL Server Management Studio that my username is able to connect successfully. In the Studio, when I right click on database and go to Properties, on the left panel, under Connection, it shows my connection as domain\username, exactly what I provided in the Java code.
2. In Java, after connecting with `Integrated security = true`, I printed out `con.getMetaData().getUserName()` and see that it matched what I provided.

Any ideas on this? I went through numerous threads on this but could not find a way yet to get my code to work.

On thinking about this, now I start to wonder how will SQL Server authenticate my Java code with my Windows password? If so, what is the way to connect using a username other than the logged in user? I am very confused.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you supply a Username and Password that's using SQL Login authentication. You cannot supply a Username and Password for Windows/Domain authentication - Windows authentication works based on the client process's authentication token validated by a shared trust (e.g.: a Domain controller).

Comment: That makes complete sense. Very different from my experience with Oracle, but I understand now. Thank you!

Comment: Admins - How do I mark AlwaysLearning's comment as the answer?